# How to fetch particular row data from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named `tbl_1` (columns: `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`) and `tbl_2` (columns: `id`, `email`, `phone`).

I want to fetch the data of certain student, for example `abc` with `id = 2`). How can I do this in MySQL?
Note: I don't want to fetch all students data.

This one is for all the data:

```
SELECT 
id, firstname, lastname, email, phone 
FROM tbl_1, tbl_2 
WHERE tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id
```

Comment: that is just bad structure, why you didnt you put all those fields in one table?

Comment: _that is just bad structure..._ Why do you think so? Are you familiar with db normalization? @Zeljka

Comment: @B001ᛦ I am. Are you?

Comment: If you were familiar with that topic than you wouldn't have posted this comment above! Just think about a person that can have different emails and phone numbers. But you still didn't tell us **why** you dislike this structure @Zeljka

Comment: There may be cases where you just need the id, first name and the last name, so it isn't really bad.

Comment: @B001ᛦ explain which rule I violate

Comment: _explain which rule I violate..._ Tell us **why** you dislike OP's design instead of asking counter questions @Zeljka

Comment: @sahil - please ignore this petty quarrel. You can simply add `AND id=2` to the end of your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the selected id. Ex:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone 
FROM tbl_1, tbl_2 
WHERE tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id 
AND tbl_1.id = 2
```

Or using join:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone 
FROM tbl_1
INNER JOIN tbl_2 
ON tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id
WHERE tbl_1.id = 2;
```

Comment: Or better use `JOIN`

Comment: thank you jeprubio. it works. this is just an example i had written to ask question. I have many tables and i can't add all these data in one single table. so, i want to use two tables.

Comment: No problem, it sometimes makes sense to separate the fields in different tables (relation not 1-1 or depending on the field data size...) Glad to help